# Joomla : How to stop showing related videos in jv_youtube at the end of video

Tags: joomla, youtube

I am using youtube video in joomla where the code is like this :-

```
[jv_youtube url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Di0IOQssOM&rel=0" width="600" height="540" responsive="yes" autoplay="no" rel="0"][/jv_youtube]
```

What I want is to stop showing related other videos come at the end of video. I want to replay the video or just stop.

I know how we can stop this - by putting ?rel=0 but you can see I have already put &rel=0 and also rel="0" but still the issue persists.

Any idea? Anyone? How to do this in Joomla?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but could not find any clean solution for this but still somehow I managed to get it working as the way I wanted (rel=0)

I put this script :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var ifrm = jQuery(".jv-youtube iframe");
ifrm.attr("src", ifrm.attr("src")+"?rel=0");
});
</script>
```

This class - jv-youtube  will always be there before iframe in case of joomla.

Thanks.